# Bijective linear map determined by what it does to basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. I have shown for when they are both finite dimensional if there is exists a bijective linear map $\phi$ acting on the bases then $\phi$ is also is a bijective linear map between V and W. 
I implicitly used the fact that it was a injection by letting $\phi(a_i)=b_i$ because you can reorder basis elements if necessary. And $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,...b_n\}$ are the bases for V and W. 
when neither $V$ and $W$ have finite dimension how do I show that if $\phi$ is a bijective linear map between the bases (both infinite sets) then $\phi $ is a objective linear map between $V$ and $W$?

Comment: @CameronBuie its been edited

Comment: What do you mean by "objective linear map"? Does this mean "linear map that takes a basis to a basis bijectively"?

Answer (score 1):

This is (probably) not a complete answer, but I wanted to share my thoughts:

The general principle is: Let $V,W$ be vector spaces, $B_V$ be a basis of $V$ and $\phi : B_V \to W$ be any function. Then there is a unique linear map $\bar{\phi} : V \to W$, such that $\bar{\phi}(x)= \phi(x)$ for all $x\in B_V$.

Proof:
Suppose we have a linear map $\bar{\phi} : V \to W$, such that $\bar{\phi}(x)= \phi(x)$ for all $x\in B_V$. Let $v\in V$. Then there are $v_1,\dots,v_k \in B_V$ and $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_k\in \mathbb{K}$ (your underlying field) with $v = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i$. Hence: $\bar{\phi}(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \phi(v_i)$. So $\bar{\phi}$ is uniquely determined, if it exists.
We shall now prove the existence of said map. Let $\bar{\phi} : V\to W, \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \phi(v_i)$. This function is well-defined, since every $v\in V$ as a unique representation has a linear combination of vectors in $B_V$. It is easy to see, that $\bar{\phi}$ is linear. Finally, we have $\bar{\phi}(x)= \phi(x)$ for all $x\in B_V$.

I'm not sure, what your exact question is (what do you mean by "objective linear map"?). If $\phi$ (which is a bit different then your $\phi$) is injective (i.e. the image of $\phi$ is linearly idenpendent and hence a basis of some subspace of $W$), then so is $\bar{\phi}$. On the other hand (my) $\phi$ cannot be surjective. I am not sure, whether it may have some simple property, such that $\bar{\phi}$ is bijective, but I doubt it.